# Why is Sarah rebuked for laughing whereas Avraham is not?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, vayera, parashat-lech-lecha, abraham, sarah

In parshat Lech Lecha Avraham laughs when he hears that he'll have a son. God even tells Avraham to call his son Yitzchak which means "he will laugh" straight after that. In parshat Vayera however, Sarah laughs when she hears that she'll have a son and she is rebuked by God and Avraham for this apparent lack of faith in God.

Why this seemingly double standard? Why doesn't Avraham get rebuked for his lack of faith?

Comment: I think this has been asked before. Something relating to Avraham laughing only to G-d and Sarah doing so in front of others? Similarly Moshe was not punished when he might have "suggested" that G-d could not satisfy the people with meat.

Comment: Yes. Definitely a classic question. The answer you suggest sounds strange, who is Sarah laughing to? Actually doesn't it even say וצחקה בקרבה?

Comment: @CashCow, I thought that Sarah was in the ohel when she laughed

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20080509162804/http://www.math.wustl.edu/~msh210/torah_vayera.html

Comment: @msh210 the link you posted seems so forced. Davka the exact opposite is happening. The passuk says ותצחק שרה בקרבה לאמר. And the fact that Torah uses the word לאמר does not mean she said it out loud which is extremely clear from the word בקרבה.

Comment: There does not seem to be any meaningful difference between the two passages. Both laugh, both are reassured (compare Genesis 17:19-21 with 18:13-14).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The commentators have several different approaches here. [Sources are from a shiur my father gives. Text copied either from Sefaria (first two) or his sourcesheet (last two).]

Rashi's take (17:17), based on Targum Onkelos, is that Avraham laughed out of joy, while Sarah's laugh was out of disbelief.

> ויפל אברהם על פניו ויצחק. זה תירגם אנקלוס וחדי, לשון שמחה, ושל שרה לשון מחוך למדת שאברהם האמין ושמח, ושרה לא האמינה ולגלגה. וזהו שהקפיד הקדוש ברוך הוא על שרה ולא הקפיד על אברהם:

The Or Hachaim (18:13) says no, the Torah uses the same word (צ.ח.ק.) both times, so how can you translate it differently? Rather, the issue is in the timing -- Avraham laughed when he heard the news, but Sarah didn't believe that she would have a child until she actually saw her body change and her period return.

> ויאמר ה' אל אברהם וגו'. צריך לדעת אומרו תיבת זה, עוד למה אמר תיבת לאמר. גם כל הכתוב מיותר שלא היה לו לומר אלא למה צחקה:
>   אכן הכוונה היא להיות שמצינו בפרשה הקודמת כי אברהם גם כן צחק כשאמר לו ה' בשורת הזרע דכתיב (פ' י''ז) ויפול אברהם וגו' ויצחק ולא ראינו שהקפיד ה' על שצחק אברהם, ויאמר האומר מה נשתנית צחיקת שרה מצחיקת אברהם. ומצינו לאונקלוס שנתכוון לתרץ זה במה שתרגם צחיקת אברהם וחדי וצחיקת שרה וחייכת אבל על מי סמך הקב''ה להבין ב' פירושים משונים בתיבה אחת:
>   אכן הנכון הוא כי הקב''ה דקדק בדבריו טעם הקפדתו על שרה ולא על אברהם, ותמצא כי אברהם בעת הבשורה צחק מה שאין כן שרה לא צחקה בעת שנתבשרה אלא בעת שראתה עדנה כאומרו ותצחק שרה וגו' אחרי בלותי היתה לי עדנה הרי זה מגיד כי לא נתאמת אצלה הבטחת הלידה עד שראתה השינוי ועל זה הקפיד ה', והוא אומרו למה זה צחקה פי' על צחוק זה אני מקפיד ולא על צחוק שלך, והטעם כי צחוק זה כוונתה לומר האף אמנם שנתאמת אצלה אחר מעשה שתלד וזה יגיד כי לא האמינה ולא סמכה דעתה על הבטחתי אותה כי הוא דבר פלא היפלא מה' דבר וגו':

The Bechor Shor (17:17) defends Avraham because he bowed in gratitude when laughing.

> ויפל אברהם על פניו ויצחק:
>   נפילתו והשתחויתו מוכיחים שהאמין, כי דרך הודאה הוא שמח וצחק והודה והשתחוה. 
>   ואמר: כמה נס גדול, וכמה טובה בכללה שמשנה סדרו של עולם עלי לטובה...

In case you haven't noticed, the commentators quoted above all defend Avraham's actions, for different reasons. The Midrash Hagadol (17:17) is one of the few who actually criticize Avraham. He says that Avraham was meant to understand from Sarah's rebuke that what he did was wrong without explicitly being told so.

> מפני מה מיחה הכתוב בשרה ולא מיחה באברהם, שנאמר "ויפל אברהם על פניו ויצחק"? אלא ללמדך ששנים שעשו דבר שלא כהוגן והיה אחד מהם גדול ואחד קטן ואין ממחין אלא בקטן והגדול מרגיש מאליו.

Comment: I don't believe that I've learned Rashi to Vayeira, but that is what it sounds like to me

Comment: THe last answer also refers to Moshe speaking to the sons of Aharon when he asked why the korbon (in Parshas Shmini) had been burnt. Aharon understood from the criticism of his sons that he also was being criticized. That is why he answered and spoke of himself.

Comment: @Scimonster I don't think your explanation of the Or Hachaim is clear. According to him, the laughing was a sign of belief and Avraham laughed before the event, whereas according to OHC, Sarah only laughed after the event which showed a lack of faith. I'll add that I don't like this approach because according to the passukim it seems quite clear that Sarah does indeed laugh before she becomes pregnant (unless I've misunderstood something in the OHC).

Comment: @EliezerSteinbock "The event" that she laughed at is her body changing to *be able to* get pregnant.

Comment: הרי זה מגיד כי לא נתאמת אצלה הבטחת הלידה עד שראתה השינוי ועל זה הקפיד ה'

Comment: And האף אמנם שנתאמת אצלה אחר מעשה שתלד

Comment: I really don't get the OHC's answer. Or it's just super forced. Either I'd edit your answer to clarify the position of the OHC.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think it is obvious that there are two different laughters being spoken of. Avraham Avinu heard it from Hashem Himself. Obviously, Avraham is not laughing off Hashem's word. His laughing is because he already envisions it happening, and being so outlandish he laughs about it.

Sarah Imanu, on the other hand, heard it now for the first time, from people (it seemed). There is no reason to be excited about it already happening just because someone mentioned it. Her laughter was therefore obviously laughing off the ridiculous idea. She didn't, God forbid, knowingly dismiss a promise from Hashem.

In fact, there is really not much to complain about, since she actually had no reason to think it will happen. Therefore, the Pasuk just says, is anything too hard for Hashem? The complaint is merely about laughing it off; about dismissing it so easily.

The Medrash says that this complaint was just an excuse for Hashem to communicate with her.

Comment: Is this your own explanation or taken from somewhere?

Comment: @scimonster I haven't seen it anywhere.

Comment: Then you might want to make it more clear that this is an original thought.

Comment: I believe this is the Chizkuni's explanation

Comment: חזקוני בראשית פרק יח 

(יב) ותצחק שרה כשבא תשרי אחר בשורת המלאכים וראתה בעצמה שלא נתעברה מיד נתייאשה מן הבשורה שלא היה לה רק ששה חדשים עד הפסח, ולא האמינה כמו אברהם לפי שאברהם עמד לו מפי הקדוש ברוך הוא ולכן האמין אבל שרה לא שמעה אלא מפי המלאכים והיא היתה סבורה שבני אדם הם, והיתה מסתכלת במעיה ואומרת אפשר קרביים הללו טוענין ולד, מיד, באותו פרק בתשרי ויאמר ה' אל אברהם למה זה צחקה שרה, למועד אשוב אליך...

Comment: @sam Thanks. That is indeed close. My point though, is to prove that there is no other way to understand it. Being that she heard it from people we can't interpret her laughter to mean excitement, for it didn't make sense to be excited.